# Understanding a proof that every subset of the natural numbers is either finite or countable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Below is a lemma and its proof, not written out in full, just up to the point where it confuses me.

> Lemma: Every subset of naturals is either finite or countable

--

> Proof: Let $M \subseteq \mathbb N.$ If $M = \emptyset,$ them $M$ is finite, so assume $M \ne \emptyset.$ Define $M_1 = M$. By WOP, $M_1$ has a least element $n_1.$ Let $M_2 = M_1 - \{n_1\}$. If $M_2 = \emptyset$, then $M_1$ has one element and so it is finite. Else, $M_2$ has a least element $n_2$ with $n_2 > n_1.$
>
> Let $m \ge 1$ and suppose for any $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}, \ M_{k+1} = M_k - \{n_k\}$ where $n_k$ is the least element of $M_k.$ If $M_{m + 1} = \emptyset,$ then $\color{red}{M = M_m = \{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\}}$ which is finite. Else, $M_{m + 1}$ has a least element $n_{m+1}$ with $n_{m+1} > n_m.$ Thus if $M_m \ne \emptyset$ for any natural $m$, then some subset $S$ of $M$ admits the enumeration $n_1, n_2, n_3, \ldots$ meaning $S$ is countable.

Suppose $M_{m+ 1} = \emptyset.$ Then $M_m - \{n_m\} = \emptyset.$ If a set $S$ is empty after removing a single element from $S$, then it must've been the case that $|S| = 1.$ Thus we must have $|M_m| = 1$. If this is true, how do we get the part in red in the proof above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo and that the author meant to say that$$M=\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m\}.$$

Comment: How does $M =\{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\}$ follow from $M_{m+1} = \emptyset?$

Comment: Since $\emptyset=M_{m+1}=M\setminus\{n_m\}$, $M_m=\{n_m\}$. Now, since $\{n_m\}=M_m=M_{m-1}\setminus\{n_{m-1}\}$, $M_{m-1}=\{n_{m-1},n_m\}$. And so on, until you get$$M=M_1=\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{m-1},n_m\}.$$